# References in aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a view which displays two different sets of data:
Let's say proposalDetails and orderDetails.
I have inherited some code that attempts to backup these two classes as members.

The problem with the code in comments below is that the class functions are not cloned. Only the members. On the other hand keeping the 2 classes as references works just fine when I switch back and forth (between proposalDetails and orderDetails)

Is there a reason that keeping reference is bad/incorrect practice?

**Is there any danger that when I modify proposalDetails, orderDetails  is modified too?**

```
switchView(viewName) {       
 if (viewName === 'proposal') {

      //this.orderBackup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.orderDetails));
      //this.orderDetails = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.proposalDetails));

      //'Cloning' the member like this does not include all the class functions
      //I changed it to keep just the reference

      this.orderBackup = this.orderDetails;
      this.orderDetails = this.proposalDetails;

      $('#view_ordered').removeClass('active');
      $('#view_proposal').addClass('active');

      this.formDisabled = true;
      return;
    }

    this.orderDetails = this.orderBackup;
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. If you change `orderDetails` you will also change `orderDetailsBackup`.

Comment: @fabioLuz Thanks for pointing this out. I corrected the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking isn't specific to Aurelia at all, other than the fact Aurelia promotes the use of classes for your view-models. I have used the JSON trick you are using to do simple clones of classes, it gets the job done and to be honest isn't the worse thing you can do.

Worth pointing out that Lodash has some great utility functions for cloning objects both deep and shallow as well.

Comment: I guess it's not specific to aurelia. But why do I need any cloning at all? Is there any danger that when I modify proposalDetails, orderDetails  is modified too? I have updated the code I posted

Comment: The thing with Javascript is everything is passed by reference. In most cases, this can be great. But in your situation and a situation I have found myself in, sometimes you want to store state and then use that to revert changes or make comparisons. This is why solutions like RxJs are popular, because they handle state and offer immutability (which is what you're after). When you assign an object to a variable and you change it, because you're just referencing a pointer anything that is assigned that object gets the changes. It's just a Javascript design feature.

Comment: But I 'saved' the ref in  this.orderBackup = this.orderDetails, Modifying orderDetails should not affect orderBackup.  In Java too everything is passed by refrerence. But orderBackup  would not be modifiable

Comment: Directly assigning a reference will not clone it, but point to its existing reference. In your posted code `this.orderBackup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.orderDetails));` is making a clone of the `orderDetails` object. If you were to go `this.orderBackup = this.orderDetails` you're just creating a pointer to the original reference. What you have works well.